# Sympy function evaluation

Tags: python, sympy, evaluate

I have a little question about sympy.
I did load the library with :

```
from sympy import *
```

At some point of my program I would like to evaluate a function.

```
x=Symbol('x', real=True)
sqrt(1-x).subs(x, 9).evalf()
>>> 2.82842712474619*I
```

Sympy answer me complex value but i would like an error as in basic python :

```
sqrt(-1)
>>> ValueError: math domain error
```

Someone know how to do that using sympy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I don't think you can make it yell that way, because that's a scientific library so it is made for supporting imaginary numbers, but you can change it a bit:

```
x=Symbol('x', real=True)
v = sqrt(1-x).subs(x, 9).evalf()

if not v.is_real:
    raise ValueError, "math domain error"
```

or you can create a function:

```
def assert_real(v):
    if not v.is_real:
        raise ValueError, "math domain error"
    return v
```

so you can do:

```
x = Symbol('x', real=True)
v = assert_real(sqrt(1-x).subs(x, 9).evalf())
```

Comment: I was thinking about the same solution. Thanks for answering, it's kind of solution for me!

Comment: You may need to do `evalf(chop=True)` in general, to clear out small imaginary parts.

Comment: You want `not v.is_real`, not `v.is_imaginary`. `is_imaginary` is only for pure imaginary numbers. `(1 + 2*I).is_imaginary` will be `False`.